How can I get this function properly infer the return type?
class Foo {
  name: string;

  constructor({name}: {name: string}) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Bar<T extends Foo> {
  foo: T;

  constructor({foo}: {foo: T}) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}

class CustomFoo extends Foo {
  xxx: string;

  constructor({
    name,
    xxx,
  }: {
    name: string,
    xxx: string,
  }) {
    super({name});
    this.xxx = xxx;
  }
}

class CustomBar<F extends Foo> extends Bar<F> {
  customField: string;

  constructor({
    foo,
    customField,
  }: {
    foo: F,
    customField: string,
  }) {
    super({foo});
    this.customField = customField;
  }
}

const doSomething = <
  B extends Bar<F>,
  F extends Foo,
>(
  FooConstructor: { new(...args : any[]): F; },
  BarConstructor: { new(...args : any[]): B; },
): B => {
  return new BarConstructor({});
}

const mything = doSomething(CustomFoo, CustomBar);

Unfortunately the type of mything is Bar<CustomFoo> whereas I require it to be CustomBar<CustomFoo>.
I would have expected TypeScript to infer the return type.
How can I write doSomething in such a way so that it returns the inferred type rather than the 'base' type?
I'm not sure what to try.

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that declares Foo, Bar, CustomFoo, and CustomBar, otherwise it risks being closed as needing debugging details.

TS inference doesn't work that way; there are no higher kinded types (HKT), nor will TS infer/instantiate type arguments unless you directly call a generic function.  Unless you go through a lot of trouble to try to simulate HKTs, were the cure is worse than the disease, you're just going to have to manually instantiate things like this. Does that fully address the question (even though the answer is not what you'd like)? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I feel like I tried everything except your suggestion.
const mything = doSomething(CustomFoo, CustomBar<CustomFoo>);
Is what I was looking for, thanks!

Unfortunately, TypeScript's inference will not give you what you want, nor is there an way to express what you're doing in a seamless or general way in TypeScript. TypeScript doesn't have "call types" as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#40179. You'd like to be able to say: given BarConstructor of some generic type, what type will you get when you call the constructor, keeping in mind that it might be generic and depend on its input or how it is called.  But unless you actually go ahead and call a constructor directly, there's no way to capture that. You can use conditional types like InstanceType, but that ends up losing track of any generics.  The general limitation is around higher-kinded types, as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#1213. There's just no great way to deal with generics-of-generics.
When you call doSomething(CustomFoo, CustomBar), F is inferred as CustomFoo, and then B has to be inferred as a subtype of Bar<CustomFoo>. But TypeScript loses the thread here; it can't "plug in" CustomFoo anywhere, since that would require higher-kinded types.  The best you could get is CustomBar<Foo>, but what actually happens is that it falls back to the constraint of Bar<CustomFoo>.  TypeScript's inference will only ever give you CustomBar<Foo> or Bar<CustomFoo> here.

Instead you'll need to work around it. One workaround you can use in the example given is an instantiation expression on CustomBar, to tell the compiler that you are specifically concerned with plugging CustomFoo into the type argument for that constructor:
const mything = doSomething(CustomFoo, CustomBar<CustomFoo>);
// const mything: CustomBar<CustomFoo>

Now when the compiler infers B, the only option is CustomBar<CustomFoo>, and then everything works out.
Playground link to code
